# PHP If else statement need some help please

Tags: php, if-statement

I am still very much learning php, i have been struggling to get the following to work, i hope someone will no where i have gone wrong,

Thank you in advance

```
$sageOutput[$sagecount]["paid_yes_no"]= 

if $orders->fields['payment_amount'] = 0 echo 'NOT PAID'; 

else echo 'PAID';
```

Comment: whats happening in code ?

Comment: Thanks so Much Guns

 $sageOutput[$sagecount]["paid_yes_no"]= $orders->fields['payment_amount'] == 0 ? 'NOT PAID' : 'PAID';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to follow the syntax

```
if($orders->fields['payment_amount'] == 0)
   echo 'NOT PAID'; 
else 
   echo 'PAID';
```

while you checking an condition always use `==`.

Comment: *+1*: This is correct, but I'd just use curly braces to explicitly define the blocks (that way, you can also execute more than one statement under the `if`/`else` block).

Comment: hi thanks so much for your reply

I tried that

$sageOutput[$sagecount]["paid_yes_no"]= 
 
 if($orders->fields['payment_amount'] == 0)
   echo 'NOT PAID'; 
else 
   echo 'PAID';

but still have a error ???

Comment: @TicRacing: You should really learn PHP first, before attempting to program in PHP. This community is very eager to assist and explain, but it's not a "please write my code"-site. To properly learn PHP, you should get a good book (the PHP manual is a great reference as well). But to get started, you might try [CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php).

Answer (score 2):

You are doing an assignment (with =) instead of a comparison (with ==).

Also please always use {} to wrap your if-else-blocks. Ask apple about goto fail :-)

```
if($x == "something") {
    do this;
} else {
    do that;
}
```

is much better to read.

Last but not least echo will send the content to the client (the web browser) and not only assign it to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to write this is

```
$sageOutput[$sagecount]["paid_yes_no"]= $orders->fields['payment_amount'] == 0 ? 'PAID' : 'NOT PAID'
```

Comment: "*The best way to write this*" — I agree a ternary expression is shorter, but if it affects readability, I'd rather use a `if` / `else` block instead :)

Comment: I agree @AmalMurali, but it depends on the style of coding

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($orders->fields['payment_amount'] == 0){
    echo "Not Paid";
}else{
    echo "Paid";
}
```

Be careful when using `=` as:

```
$a = 0;   // Assignment
$a == 0;  // Equal
$a === 0; // Identical
```

Answer (score 0):

try
if you wnat store value in `$sageOutput[$sagecount]["paid_yes_no"]` according condition then

```
if ($orders->fields['payment_amount'] == 0) 
  $sageOutput[$sagecount]["paid_yes_no"] = 'NOT PAID'; 
else 
  $sageOutput[$sagecount]["paid_yes_no"]= 'PAID';
```

if you want echo values using condition then try

```
if ($orders->fields['payment_amount'] == 0) 
  echo 'NOT PAID'; 
else 
  echo 'PAID';
```